# Get ID from foreach and route without some letters in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a new php project with CodeIgniter and I have few questions about it.

**1 -** I created news script, for now I done backend and I'm working on frontend. At frontend I already set last news, but I want to show how many comments at one news there are. I used `foreach`, but I don't know what's the best method to do next in MVC framework.

```
<?php
foreach ($query as $news)
{
    echo $news->title . "<br>" . $news->content . "<br>";
    $commentnum = $this->db->select('id_comment, id_news')->where('id_news', $news->id)->get('comments');
    echo $commentnum->num_rows();
}
?>
```

Okay.. that's some piece of code which I use in other projects. What's the best way to use that code in MVC pattern?

**2 -** At this news script I have some controller which is named News and in it are functions post, cats and tags. And code which I'm using now, but not works like I want:

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = "news/post/$1";
```

So how to exclude post, cats and tags from the route -> If I type `news/tags/first`, to get the tag first and not error, that the post doesn't exist. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick to the MVC pattern (and I would suggest you do as it makes things easier in the long run of managing your application, or updating its looks) then do the following:

Instead of `echo`ing out all your 'news' info, store it into an array, and pass that array to the VIEW.  Let the VIEW then just go through that array (of news & related comments) and output it.

That way your logic for assembling this news / comment structure remains in the controller, and the view just spits out the data, and does not ITERATE through the `$query` object.

This creates a clean separation of controller, model & view.

**Example:**

```
foreach ($query as $news)
{
    $comments = $this->db->select('id_comment, id_news')->where('id_news', $news->id)->get('comments');        
    $data['news'][$news->id]['title'] = $news->title;
    $data['news'][$news->id]['content'] = $news->content;
    $data['news'][$news->id]['num_comments'] = $comments->num_rows();

    if($data['news'][$news->id]['num_comments'] > 0){
        foreach ($comments as $entry){
              $data['news'][$news->id][$entry->id]['comment'] = $entry->content;  
        }
    }
}
```

As far as your routing issue is concerned you need to properly route the URI to the METHOD in your controller:

```
$route['tags/(:any)'] = "news/tags/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "news/posts/$1";
```

The `$route['(:any)']` I haven't personally tried, **but** I would suggest you format your URI to be something like `http://domain.com/post/name-of-post` as opposed to `http://domain.com/name-of-post`, it will just be cleaner for routing keeping it seperate, because the above route `$route['(:any)']` forces you to create CUSTOM routes (a whitelist) for everything else like tags / links / users / etc;

Comment: The code from example is in controller? I have never actually programmed with more then one [] at $data, so I don't know how to call this in view then.

About part 2 I have created main controller news and I would like to have URLs domain.com/title-of-article or domain.com/tags/first. So there is the problem when in the address is "tags" and the route think, this is the title of article, but I would like to take that as tag (which is another function in this controller).

Comment: @user1257255, yes the code above goes into your controller, you would then call the data easily from the view using the variable `$news[0]['title']` which would output the title for the first news entry, of course you could `foreach` the `$news` array and output it just like you are now with the `$query`.